# angular 6 how to get *ngIf if object is empty

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6 and trying to check if object is empty or not with below code. as per my understanding it should be printing either of statement, but its printing both, what wrong I am doing
 I am emitting Fake from child to parent

@Input() Fake: any = {};

```
<pre *ngIf="Fake?.length <= 0">
<h2> empty </h2>
</pre>
<pre *ngIf="Fake?.length >= 0">
        <h2>NOT EMPTY </h2>
 </pre>
```

Comment: fake is a object. not an array. Can't use the length for an object

Comment: Both `*ngIf`'s contain an `=` equal sign. So if the array is empty, both `pre` tags are shown. So the first `*ngIf` should be `Fake?.length <= 0` and the second `Fake?.length > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`Fake` is an object. not an array. use `object.keys` to get the object keys.

```
checkFake(){
   let keys = Object.keys(this.fake)
   return keys;
}

<pre *ngIf="checkFake() <= 0">
<h2> empty </h2>
</pre>
<pre *ngIf="checkFake() >= 0">
        <h2>NOT EMPTY </h2>
 </pre>
```